# How to get Outlook 2013 to encrypt using AES and not 3DES

Tags: encryption, email, aes, microsoft-outlook

In my company we are exchanging emails with a government authority once a month and they require us to encrypt those emails with encryption algorithm **AES-128, AES-192 or AES-256**. For the purpose we did purchase an **email digital id** from [Trustwave](https://ssl.trustwave.com/email-digital-id)

The computer from which we are sending the emails is running **Windows 7** and using **Outlook 2013** as email client.

The authority sent us their certificates and I did install them and attached them to their contact in Outlook. Then I did import our newly purchased certificate in Outlook from **Options > Trust Center > Email Security**
and setup the required algorithm (AES-128).

All looks fine and now we try to send email to the authority but the email explicitly gets encrypted with **3DES** algorithm ...

Then I send encrypted email with the same settings to my colleague and the email is encrypted with the right algorithm - AES-128 ...

I am not able to solve this problem in the last two weeks, I tried multiple times to reinstall all the certificates, to setup all possible different settings related to email encryption in Outlook, tried using [The Bat](https://www.ritlabs.com/en/products/thebat/) email client but nothing solves the problem. **Emails get explicitly encrypted with 3DES** and the authority is not accepting our emails ...

I decided to ask here so I am open to suggestions how to approach this problem...

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from the following [Microsoft Outlook blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dvespa/2018/10/29/outlook-smime-encryption-3des-aes256/), your client needs to advertise to the recipient server that it can send mails in AES. As stated in the article:

> The recommended approach for fixing this is for the recipient to
>   change the certificate to include the **SMIME Capabilities attribute**. 
>   This way the recipient can advertise to Outlook what algorithms the
>   sender should use to send encrypted message to the recipient.

Hope this helps!